# Db2 on Cloud: "Service Broker returned error status code 500" when trying to add service credentials

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I am using Db2 on Cloud and receive the above error when trying to create credentials.

Comment: Let me guess: Are you using the free, non-production Lite plan? There have been similar questions here before. There are ongoing service migrations.

Comment: Hi Henrik, thanks for responding. I am using the non-production lite plan. I apologise, I am new to using IBM cloud and DB2. What significance do service migrations have?

Comment: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-changes-to-the-lite-plan-june-july-2021- Apparently, they are reshuffling resources and software. I don't have details.

Comment: Facing the same issue since. I have a DB2 Lite resource I created a month ago and I'm not able to access the UI. I created a new account and tried to create a DB2 Lite resource but I'm getting the same error above. This has been since 31st July for me. If anyone can help resolve this issue, it would be greated appreciated. I suspect the issue lies with IBM. Update: I was able to create a new resource in London region and access my database. Dallas (US-South) no longer works. Hopefully IBM resolves the issues with Dallas so I can access my databases residing there. I suggest you create the reso

Comment: Hi,

Go to Access IAM --> Service ID => Create ID

Service Credentials => Advanced options => Select Service ID => Select service ID generated previously. 

This worked for me.